# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int

Tags: quality-center, sql, hp-alm

I am writing this query in HP ALM 11.52 and facing the error
"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '*userid*' to data type int"

Query is

```
select * 
from Testcycl
join Audit_Log on tc_test_id = au_entity_id
```

I know the *userid* is a string and it is unable to convert it to data type int. How can we resolve this error in the HP ALM Query builder?

Comment: I voted to close this question here and move it to Stack Overflow. You will get better answers there - or likely the is answer there if you just search a bit. [Google is your friend:](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=HP+ALM+11.52+and+facing+the+error+%22Conversion+failed+when+converting+the+varchar)

Comment: Peter, I'm not so sure. There's no guarantee that the query you enter into HP ALM is actual SQL or if it's just "SQL-ish". This is certainly on topic here, and is in all honest a well worded question (does need a small amount of formatting, but that's minor.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that the problem is that you are trying to search for all types of events and since AU_ENTITY_ID allow NULLs you might receive such error.

Please try to use LEFT/RIGHT/FULL JOIN (according to what you are trying to achieve) and not using INNER JOIN since converting NULL to INT value might result a failure (unless you are protecting your search with ISNULL()).

Comment: If that is correct, wouldn't a `WHERE AU_ENTITY_ID IS NOT NULL` work even better?